# Unmet dependencies, lost archives, and missing source packages while upgrading kernel to 4.2.0

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

While trying to update my kernel I found I was missing archives. This is the error message on my computer (and when I try to open synaptic to uninstall the packages)

```
The package linux-headers-4.2.0-040200 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

This message appears even when I try `sudo apt-get update`, `clean`, `install -f` and most other `apt` commands. I also tried `sudo apt-get source linux-headers-4.2.0-040200` but it came up with:

```
Unable to find a source package for linux-headers-4.2.0-040200
```

I haven't figured out how to fully remove the package through the terminal rather than synaptic (and I can't use synaptic because of the error message which closes synaptic). I followed the instructions from this website to update my kernel http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/08/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-2-0-in-linux.html (the uninstall command didn't work). Here is the code for when I run the installation command (I already checked and I have the wget files)
When I run the dpkg installation it always gets stuck on unpacking the headers which looks like this:

```
eliaszeus@Batman:~$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.2.0*.deb linux-image-4.2.0*.deb
[sudo] password for eliaszeus: 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc2.
(Reading database ... 292589 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc2_4.2.0-040200rc2.201507160938_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc2 (4.2.0-040200rc2.201507160938) ...
```

I've left this for several hours before with no luck. If somebody could help me figure out how to solve one of these: Either solving the missing archives, or getting past unpacking the headers. Sorry if the code is bad this is my first time writing a question and couldn't figure the code block out.

Comment: @mchid A clickjack?

Comment: Okay, here's your answer. I have assumed you are running amd64. If you are running i386, let me know and I will change the instructions accordingly. Please post any errors, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install these packages one-by-one or you will run into dependency issues.

First, make a temporary directory to work in:

```
cd
mkdir KERNEL;cd KERNEL
```

Next, download the first of the dependencies to be installed:

```
wget 'http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2-unstable/linux-headers-4.2.0-040200_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_all.deb'
```

Install the first dependency:

```
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.2.0-040200_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_all.deb'
```

Clear the directory:

```
rm *.deb
```

Download the next of the dependencies:

```
wget 'http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2-unstable/linux-headers-4.2.0-040200-generic_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_amd64.deb'
```

Install the dependency:

```
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.2.0-040200-generic_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_amd64.deb'
```

Clear the directory:

```
rm *.deb
```

Download the kernel:

```
wget 'http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2-unstable/linux-image-4.2.0-040200-generic_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_amd64.deb'
```

Install the kernel:

```
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-image-4.2.0-040200-generic_4.2.0-040200.201508301530_amd64.deb'
```

Clear the directory:

```
rm *.deb
```

Finally, return to your home directory and remove the temporary directory:

```
cd ..
rm KERNEL
```

Also, while you are at it, go ahead and open synaptic:

```
pkexec synaptic &
```

click on **Edit**,

then, from the drop-down menu, select **fix broken packages** just to make sure.

Finally, click **Apply** and review the changes to make sure you aren't going to gut your whole system before clicking to accept the changes.

If there are no changes to be made, everything is all good.

Please post any errors.

---

If you can't execute the commands above, you may need to purge the offending packages before you begin.

First, purge the kernel:

```
sudo dpkg -P 'linux-image-4.2.0-040200-generic'

sudo dpkg -P 'linux-image-4.2.0-040200rc2-generic'
```

if it says *blah blah blah is not installed*, just ignore it and move on to the next command.

Then purge the arch specific header:

```
sudo dpkg -P 'linux-headers-4.2.0-040200-generic'

sudo dpkg -P 'linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc2-generic'
```

the same for this, if it's not installed, ignore and move on.

Finally, purge the header:

```
sudo dpkg -P 'linux-headers-4.2.0-040200'

sudo dpkg -P 'linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc2'
```

---

**Additionally, there have been some updates and 4.2.1 has already been released so you may want to try these instructions instead:**

Also, if there are problem with your internet connection like dropped downloads, your images could end up corrupted. To fix this, you can use `aria2` to  download instead of `wget`. Unlike `wget`, `aria2` has the ability to resume failed or interrupted downloads. First, install aria2:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

Then, make a temporary directory to work in:

```
cd
mkdir KERNEL;cd KERNEL
```

Next, download all the stuff one-by-one (just go ahead and download all the  before installing this time as it shouldn't make a difference):

```
aria2c 'http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2.1-unstable/linux-headers-4.2.1-040201_4.2.1-040201.201509211431_all.deb'

aria2c 'http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2.1-unstable/linux-headers-4.2.1-040201-generic_4.2.1-040201.201509211431_amd64.deb'

aria2c 'http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2.1-unstable/linux-image-4.2.1-040201-generic_4.2.1-040201.201509211431_amd64.deb'
```

Install the first dependency:

```
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.2.1-040201_4.2.1-040201.201509211431_all.deb'
```

Now, the next dependency:

```
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.2.1-040201-generic_4.2.1-040201.201509211431_amd64.deb'
```

and then, install the kernel:

```
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-image-4.2.1-040201-generic_4.2.1-040201.201509211431_amd64.deb'
```

Clear the directory:

```
rm *.deb
```

Finally, return to your home directory and remove the temporary directory:

```
cd ..
rm KERNEL
```

Please post any errors.

Comment: The first commands simply wouldn't work. They became stuck on unpacking the headers every time with each one. I tried to purge everything like you said and it gave the error:  "you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in"

Comment: @EliRangel also, you were originally trying to install the realtime kernel. The link you gave was for instructions on how to install kernel 4.2 but your original dpkg output references 4.2rt so the regular kernel is the kernel I have provided instructions for. I have updated the instructions on how to purge both the rt and the regular kernel 4.2

Comment: Thank you I saw that and felt so stupid. Thank you for your in depth instructions!

Comment: @EliRangel Did it ever work? I was thinking the unpacking problem may have been because of a corrupted download. Also, don't beat yourself up, I happened to know the actual package names because I remembered seeing them when reviewing the dependencies.  In the future, you can run something like: `dpkg -l | grep 'linux-image-4.2'` or `dpkg -l | grep 'linux-headers-4.2'` to list all installed (or partially installed) packages that match one of those names.

Comment: @EliRangel Also, I was wrong anyhow, that is rc *not* rt. I guess that's a release candidate kernel and *not* a realtime kernel like I thought. Anyhow, I went ahead and provided some new instructions for version 4.2.1 which is already out and how to use aria2 instead of wget in case there is some sort of a download problem, aria2 should work better.

Comment: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D